# Can a wish spell grant new skills?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, skills, magic, wish

I was researching and trying to discern if a wish spell could give a PC a skill he does not have. I don't see anything that states it can or cannot but when compared to some of the things a wish could grant it would seem like a feasible option. Does anyone know if there is a rule for this already in place or if this would be up to DM discretion?

Answer (score 10):

*Wish* has a very specific, limited list of things it definitely can do safely:

- Duplicate spellcasting (up to certain levels based on class)
- Undo many spells and heal many afflictions, up to and including death, as stated in those spells and in *wish* itself
- Create a nonmagical item of up to 25,000 gp
- Create a magical item or upgrade a magical item<sup>1</sup>
- Grant inherent bonuses to ability scores
- Transport travelers
- Undo misfortune

So these are the things we know *wish* can do, and that will not be twisted or come at costs greater than those listed in the spell.

Everything else is covered by

> You may try to use a wish to produce greater effects than these, but doing so is dangerous. (The *wish* may pervert your intent into a literal but undesirable fulfillment or only a partial fulfillment.)

So ultimately, yes, it is purely up to the DM.

---

1. <sup>The ability to create a magical item is listed in a separate bullet from the one for creating nonmagical items, and does not list any cost limit as the nonmagical version does. Whether this means that *wish* has no limit on magical item creation is a matter of some debate. Ask your DM.</sup>

Comment: The spell description specifically says "greater effects than these" though. Depending on the number of skill ranks awarded, is learning a new skill (which will give a bonus to rolls only in a specific situation) really a "greater effect" than granting an inherent bonus to an ability score (which will give bonuses to many skills, and possibly also saves, spellcasting, hitpoints, etc)?

Comment: @Tack that's an argument for your DM, not for me. Personally, though, I could see situations where even a single skill rank is greater than a +5 inherent bonus: if you were one rank short of meeting a requirement for a feat it prestige class, say. I'd probably still let *wish* do it, but it is a greater effect.